# Como verificar se um arquivo que contem uma palavra especifica existe?

Tags: php, array, arquivo

Estou utilizando PHP, e em uma pasta do servidor contem arquivos com estes nomes:

```
T3497012@16-01-02:21@GEOTIMBRAG1A@PanServidor.json
T3497012@16-01-02:22@GEOTIMBRAG1B@PanServidor.json
T3497012@16-01-02:23@GEOTIMBRAW1@PanServidor.json
T3497012@16-01-02:24@GEOTIMBRAW21@PanServidor.json
T3497012@16-01-02:25@GEOTIMBRHDDSA@PanServidor.json
T3497012@16-01-02:26@GEOTIMBRHDDSA@Disco.json
T3497012@16-01-02:27@GEOTIMBRAG1B@Disco.json
T3497012@16-01-02:28@GEOTIMBRRTRA@Disco.json
T9997012@16-01-02:29@GEOTIMBRAW21@PanServidor.json
T1997012@16-01-02:30@GEOTIMBRHDDSA@PanServidor.json
T1997012@16-01-02:31@GEOTIMBRHDDSA@Disco.json
T9997012@16-01-02:32@GEOTIMBRAG1B@Disco.json
T9997012@16-01-02:33@GEOTIMBRRTRA@Disco.json
```

cada palavra desta entre os `@` significa algo, analisando o primeiro arquivo por exemplo:

```
T3497012@16-01-02:21@GEOTIMBRAG1A@PanServidor.json
```

`T3497012` é o id do usuario que salvou o arquivo, `16-01-02:21` é a data e a hora que ele fez isso, `GEOTIMBRAG1A` é o nome do host `Disco` o tipo e `.json` é a extensão do arquivo.

eu preciso atribuir a um array todos os nomes de arquivos que seja do id `T9997012` ficando assim:

```
$array[0] = "T9997012@16-01-02:29@GEOTIMBRAW21@PanServidor.json";
$array[1] = "T9997012@16-01-02:32@GEOTIMBRAG1B@Disco.json";
$array[2] = "T9997012@16-01-02:33@GEOTIMBRRTRA@Disco.json";
```

tentei usar preg_match() mas não consegui.

preciso tambem de um array com todos os host(GEOTIMBRAG1A) de todos os arquivos de um id. posteriormente vou precisar de um array com todos os tipo (disco, PanServidor) de um id.

Comment: acho que o comando glob deve ajudar $files = glob("/path/to/directory/* geotimbraga*.*");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [**`glob()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

Para obter todos os arquivos do ID **`T9997012`**, você pode usar o *wildcard* *****, por exemplo:

```
$array = glob('T9997012*.*');
```

Em todos os outros casos do final da pergunta você pode usar a mesma ideia.

Por exemplo, para capturar todos com o host `GEOTIMBRAG1A`

```
$array = glob('*GEOTIMBRAG1A*.*');
```